# ASP.NET Core Redirect HTTP to HTTPS

Tags: iis, asp.net, iis-10

Following Microsofts instructions for Enforcing HTTPS in ASP.NET Core and IIS 10 at https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio

The recommended changes do not appear to have an affect on redirecting http:// navigation to https:// for my site. I see a lot of blog posts reference modifying the web.config file with the rewrite rules. Changing the web.config file is not mentioned in Microsoft's documentation.

I have added this environment variable to the server: `ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT` `443`
And it does not affect the redirection at all.

I have `app.UseHttpsRedirection();` in my Startup.cs file.

Is the web.config modification the correct change to make for HTTP to HTTPS redirection?

Comment: Does your web app listen on port 443? If not, like the page says, no redirection would happen. For simplicity, please consider using IIS URL Rewrite module to perform such redirection, as that's much easier to understand and test out.

Comment: yes it is only listening on 443 now

Comment: When you said "only", I see a red flag. If it only listens at port 443, then such redirection is meaningless. I assume there was some misunderstanding, and if you cannot provide a sample somewhere for others to reproduce the same issue, it is impossible to answer. Like I said above, IIS URL Rewrite module would be a much better option to enforce, as there is almost zero ambiguity.

Comment: I setup another site in IIS withHTTP Redirect and send all requests to the  https:// version. Not sure if that's the best way to do this. The IIS URL Rewrite module is not available in the environment I'm working.